# WPF, c# -customizing a textbox display property and implement a datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I customize a textbox display property(say..border, corner radius etc..) and also implement a datatrigger for the data to be entered in it..
Or
how to customize a control's(say textbox, listbox etc.) look and feel and implement datatriggers for the same control at once through xaml...

could anybody help me with an example..

Thanks,
Sekhar.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the "display property" is usually called `ControlTemplate` in WPF. So of course you can change the whole ControlTemplate of your TextBox or other Controls and modify it any way you like. For example you can change the ControlTemplate of a Button to just show a Rectangle.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myNewButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
</ControlTemplate>


<Button Template="{StaticResource myNewButton}"/>
```

The `TemplateBinding` markup is the way to pass dependency properties, in this case `Background` to your `ControlTemplate` children.

Now if you want to add data trigger you can do that in the `ControlTemplate` itself

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myNewButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDataProperty}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetElement="rect" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: That's what am looking for...implementing controltemplate and datatriggers both for a control at once..

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options.  If you want to completely customize the visual elements of the control you can override the control style and template.  Examples are here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=VS.100).aspx.

If you want to perform easy UI changes such as a red border if some value is false you use the Style of the object:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Color="Red" ShadowDepth="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Something is invalid." />
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}" />
       </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The above is something that mimics the error templates available using a DataTrigger.  Essentially it binds to a boolean value in the viewmodel which draws a red border around a textbox if the boolean is false and clears it if the boolean is true.